# SelectedItems should stay Selected

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a Problem with my two DataGrids

The first DataGrid is used to Show Data from an SQL Database.

Now i want that, if i select one row and save it to the Datagrid2, it stays selected and won't Change.

The Problem is now that if i Change the Row, the DataGrid2 changes too.

I hope you understand my Problem.

Here's the Code

```
    Public Sub SelectItem()

    Try
        Dim rows As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
        For Each cell As DataGridCellInfo In DataGrid1.SelectedCells
            rows.Add(DataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(cell.Item))
            DataGrid1.SelectedItems.Clear()
        Next
        For Each Item As Integer In rows
            If (Item < DataGrid1.Items.Count) Then
                DataGrid1.SelectedItems.Add(DataGrid1.Items.GetItemAt(Item))

                DataGrid2.ItemsSource = DataGrid1.SelectedItems
            End If

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        GeneralMergeTools.ShowError(ex, GeneralMergeTools.FatalError.CriticalError, "ContentControl1.SelectedItem")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Kind Regards

EDIT:

I'll add here my Code for Future People who have the same or a similar Problem.

```
    Public Sub SelectItem() 'Auf Knopfdruck
    Try
        Dim dt As DataTable = CType(Me.DataGrid1.ItemsSource, DataView).Table.Clone
        For Each r1 As System.Data.DataRowView In Me.DataGrid1.SelectedItems

            Dim r2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            For Each c As System.Data.DataColumn In dt.Columns
                r2.Item(c.ColumnName) = r1.Row(c.ColumnName)
            Next
            dt.Rows.Add(r2)
            DataGrid2.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        GeneralMergeTools.ShowError(ex, GeneralMergeTools.FatalError.CriticalError, "ContentControl1.SelectedItem")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You share the same instance of Items between 2 grids:

```
DataGrid2.ItemsSource = DataGrid1.SelectedItems
```

So basically when you change property `IsSelected` in first grid by selecting it, on the second grid it's exactly the same object having also this change, so second grid also change `SelectedItem` accordingly.

To fix this behavior you need to have different instances of objects in your `ItemSource`.

Comment: This makes absolutely sence to me. 
I'll try to figure out another posibility.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my very well working Code for this matter:

```
    Public Sub SelectItem()
    Try
        Dim dt As DataTable = CType(Me.DataGrid1.ItemsSource, DataView).Table.Clone
        For Each r1 As System.Data.DataRowView In Me.DataGrid1.SelectedItems

            Dim r2 As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            For Each c As System.Data.DataColumn In dt.Columns
                r2.Item(c.ColumnName) = r1.Row(c.ColumnName)
            Next
            dt.Rows.Add(r2)
            DataGrid2.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
        Next
```